# Template Expression Error when using a template script in Azure YAML Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to run a YAML Azure Pipeline which calls in a bash template file to run the required steps. However it shows me the following error in the template script when running the pipeline

ERROR:
templates/Apps/validate/push_requirements_global.yaml@templates (Line: 21, Col: 13): A template expression is not allowed in this context
/templates/Apps/validate/push_requirements_global.yaml@templates (Line: 32, Col: 11): A template expression is not allowed in this context
/templates/Apps/validate/push_requirements_global.yaml@templates (Line: 44, Col: 11): A template expression is not allowed in this context
/templates/Apps/validate/push_requirements_global.yaml@templates (Line: 49, Col: 11): A template expression is not allowed in this context
/templates/Apps/validate/push_requirements_global.yaml@templates (Line: 60, Col: 11): A template expression is not allowed in this context

[image: Template expression error]

My template file is :

```
parameters:
  feed: ""
  vuls: ""

  steps:
  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: $(VAR_APP_PYTHON_VERSION)

  - task: PipAuthenticate@1
    inputs:
      artifactFeeds: "$(GLOBAL_FEED_NAME_PREFIX)$(FEED_NAME_SUFFIX)"
      onlyAddExtraIndex: true
#    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['getCondition.newPackages'], 'true'), eq(variables['CheckVuls.foundVul'], 'false'))

  - checkout: self

  - script: ./helper_scripts/install_pip_wheel_twine.sh
    displayName: 'Installing pip, wheel and twine'
  
  - script: ./make_directories.sh make_directories "${{ parameters.feed }}"
    name: MakeDirectories
    condition: |
      and(succeeded(), eq(variables['getCondition.newPackages'], 'true'), eq(variables['CheckVuls.foundVul'], 'false'))

  - task: PipAuthenticate@1
    inputs:
      onlyAddExtraIndex: true
    condition: |
      and(succeeded(), eq(variables['getCondition.newPackages'], 'true'), eq(variables['CheckVuls.foundVul'], 'false'))

  - bash: ./make_directories.sh download "${{ parameters.feed }}"
    name: DownloadPackages
    condition: |
      and(succeeded(), eq(variables['getCondition.newPackages'], 'true'), eq(variables['CheckVuls.foundVul'], 'false'))

  - task: AzureKeyVault@2
    inputs:
      connectedServiceName: $(VAR_SERVICE_CONNECTION)
      keyVaultName: $(GLOBAL_KV_NAME)
      secretsFilter: "FEED-PAT,ISSUES-PAT"
      runAsPreJob: false

  - bash: ./make_directories.sh check_dependencies "${{ parameters.feed }}"
    name: DeleteExistingDownloads
    condition: |
      and(succeeded(), eq(variables['getCondition.newPackages'], 'true'), eq(variables['CheckVuls.foundVul'], 'false'))

  - bash: ./make_directories.sh UnzipPackages "${{ parameters.feed }}"
    name: UnzipPackages
    condition: |
      and(succeeded(), eq(variables['getCondition.newPackages'], 'true'), eq(variables['CheckVuls.foundVul'], 'false'))

  - task: TwineAuthenticate@1
    inputs:
      artifactFeed: "$(GLOBAL_FEED_NAME_PREFIX)$(FEED_NAME_SUFFIX)"
    condition: |
      and(succeeded(), eq(variables['getCondition.newPackages'], 'true'), eq(variables['CheckVuls.foundVul'], 'false'))

  - bash: ./make_directories.sh PushPackagesToFeed "${{ parameters.feed }}"
    name: PushPackagesToFeed
    condition: | 
      and(succeeded(), eq(variables['getCondition.newPackages'], 'true'), eq(variables['CheckVuls.foundVul'], 'false'))
```

I tried changing the condition format. Once with '|' and once without but it didnt work.
The error to me does'nt make sense at all.
Please help me resolve this error :')

Comment: Parameters must contain a name and data type. Have you tried Shamrai's suggestion below? Tested on my side, it works fine. See more info about parameter from [Template parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/template-parameters?view=azure-devops#:~:text=Parameters%20must%20contain%20a%20name%20and%20data%20type.).

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the definition of the parameters to:

```
parameters:
- name: feed
  type: string
  default: ""
- name: vuls
  type: string
  default: ""
```

check this: [Runtime parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script)